# how to save entire conversation from bot into stoarge?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-blob-storage, azure-qna-maker, state-management

I have made a bot in v4 framework  using c#. I want to save the entire conversation into a storage , in a readable format . Our requirement is to save the bot conversation in a readable format or plain text. In my case only user info is getting saved not the conversation between user and the bot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a middleware for that: **[TranscriptLoggerMiddleware](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs)**

More info on [middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

The middleware will handle saving transcript for you in a storage.

Comment: i am not able to integrate this my this link with my bot.

Comment: Are you following a specific bot sample?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

I have worked on nodejs but it should be similar to C#.

For each step call the logActivity

```
const { preserveService } = require('../../../Service/dbService');



await preserveService.logActivity(step.context, userData,Any param);

logActivity : async function (turnContext, userData,Any param){
try{
    let userInfo = await userDataUtil.getUserInfo(turnContext,userData);
    colNameAndValueArray = [
        {
            [PROPERTY_NAME.COLUMN_NAME] : 'response_from',
            [PROPERTY_NAME.VALUE] : responsefrom,
            [PROPERTY_NAME.DATATYPE] : DATATYPE.STRING
        },

        {
            [PROPERTY_NAME.COLUMN_NAME] : 'user_session_id',
            [PROPERTY_NAME.VALUE] : userInfo.userId,
            [PROPERTY_NAME.DATATYPE] : DATATYPE.STRING
        },
        {
            //conversation_id
            [PROPERTY_NAME.COLUMN_NAME] : 'conversation_id',
            [PROPERTY_NAME.VALUE] : turnContext._activity.conversation.id,
            [PROPERTY_NAME.DATATYPE] : DATATYPE.STRING
        },
        {
            [PROPERTY_NAME.COLUMN_NAME] : 'is_answered',
            [PROPERTY_NAME.VALUE] : isAnswered,
            [PROPERTY_NAME.DATATYPE] : DATATYPE.BOOLEAN
        }

    ]
     await this.insert(CONFIG.DB.AUDIT_TABLE, colNameAndValueArray);

}catch(err){
    console.log(`------------------------`);
    console.log(`Error occurred while inserting audit logs`);
    console.log(err);
    console.log(`------------------------`);
}}


insert : async function(tableName, colNameAndValueArray, returnColumnName){
let query = null;
try{
    if(util.isNotEmptyString(tableName) && util.isNotEmptyArray(colNameAndValueArray)){
        let columnNames = dbUtil.getColNames(colNameAndValueArray);
        let columnValues = dbUtil.getColValues(colNameAndValueArray); 
        if(columnNames ==  null || columnValues == null){
            throw new Error('Invalid column name or value. Kindly check the value you have passed');
        }
        query = `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columnNames}) VALUES (${columnValues}) ${util.isNotEmptyString(returnColumnName)? ` RETURNING ${returnColumnName}`: ''}`;
        console.log(`------------------------`);
        console.log(`Query : ${query}`);
        console.log(`------------------------`);
        return this.executeQuery(query);
    }else{
        return Promise.reject(REQUIRED_PARAMETER_MISSING);
    }
}catch(err){
    console.log(`------------------------`);
    console.log(`Error occurred while executing insert query : ${ query != null ? query : '' }`);
    console.log(err);
    console.log(`------------------------`);
    return Promise.reject(err);
}}
```

Hope this helps

Sanjeev Guatam

Comment: can you tell code for c#? that i can add.. i am new to bot and more over i don't have any idea of node